# Read text file from text file and insert into SQL Server database using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to read in a text file using C# and insert the data from that text file into a SQL Server table.

I was using bulk insert, but have since learned that using bulk insert.
i have text which is contain 2.002405-3.SSKK170068-4.160930053856-5.FC71 hundred over data

I would like insert if is 2. only insert "002405" and if is 3 only insert "SSKK170068" in sql table. same goes to 4 and 5. Am stuck at the part at this part.

Code :

```
int i = 1;
const string connectionString ="Data Source=test\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=SAMPLE;Integrated Security=SSPI";

var dbConn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

var sr = new StreamReader(@"");
string line = sr.ReadLine();

//string[] strArray = line.Split(' ');
string[] strArray = line.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

var dt = new DataTable();

for (int index = 0; index < strArray.Count(); index++)
      dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn());

do
{
    DataRow row = dt.NewRow();

    //if (strArray.Length > 11)
    //{
    //    if (strArray[10].Contains("(1."))
    //    {
    //        //dt.Rows.Add(row);
    //    }
    //}

    //string[] itemArray = strArray[i].Split(' ');
    string[] itemArray = strArray[i].Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    row.ItemArray = strArray;
    dt.Rows.Add(row);
    i = i + 1;

    line = sr.ReadLine();
} while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line = sr.ReadLine()));

//line.Split(' ').Where(l => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(l));

dbConn.Open();

using (SqlBulkCopy bulkcopy = new SqlBulkCopy(dbConn))
{
    bulkcopy.DestinationTableName = "test_rx";
    bulkcopy.BatchSize = dt.Rows.Count;

    // Load the data to the database
    bulkcopy.WriteToServer(dt);
    dbConn.Close();

    // Close up          
    bulkcopy.Close();
}
```

Comment: Try using File.ReadAllText(addressString).Split('-')[2] to get "002405"

Comment: Its doesn't work

Comment: Need more details... what kind of error(s) do you get ?

Comment: the whole line insert 2.002405-3.SSKK170068-4.160930053856-5.FC71 in one column. should be insert based on if its 2. should be insert only 002405 and same to others as well

Comment: Its because you still miss the point and insert your LINE. You need to do a Split by '-' on the current variable you insert and use the number as the results index ...